# uploading image file in dropbox using dropbox api in php

Tags: php, dropbox-api

How can I upload image files to Dropbox with the Jimscode PHP Dropbox component for CodeIgniter? It uses the `add()` method for uploading files. It successfully uploads all other files types (e.g. pdf) to Dropbox. But when I upload image files, it uploads empty files to Dropbox. That is of 0 bytes and unable to preview that image in Dropbox. My code:

```
public function add($dbpath, $filepath, array $params = array(), $root=self::DEFAULT_ROOT)
    {
        $dbpath = str_replace(' ', '%20', $dbpath);
        $filename = rawurlencode($filepath);
        $parstr = empty($params) ? '' : '&'.http_build_query($params);
        $uri = "/files_put/{$root}/{$dbpath}?file={$filename}{$parstr}";
        //$uri = reduce_double_slashes("/files/{$root}/{$dbpath}?file={$filename}{$parstr}");
        $specialhost = 'api-content.dropbox.com';
        return $this->_post_request($uri, array('file'=>'@'.$filepath), $specialhost);
    }
```

Is there an API method I can use directly with curl and PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version you are using but the reduce_double_slashes line isn't commented out normally. That wouldn't cause some file types to upload and not others though. Is the failure with a single image or does it fail to upload with every image.

You can also set the DEBUG const in the library to true and have it write debug information out to your error log. That might help you figure out where the issue is happening.